# python3 error when passing variable into os.chdir

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am trying to find a specific pathname and pass this into os.chdir so I can run a command in that directory. I won't know the exact pathname hence why I have to run the find command. I have tried several ways to do this and each comes with a new error. The code below is one of the ways I have tried, can anyone suggest the best way to do this? Or how to fix this error?

Source Code:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system('find ~ -path "*MyDir" > MyDir.txt')

output = subprocess.check_output("cat MyDir.txt", shell=True)

os.chdir(output)

os.system("file * > MyDir/File.txt")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sub1.py", line 8, in <module>
os.chdir(output)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/Users/MyhomeDir/Desktop/MyDir\n'
```

I know that directory exists and presume it has something to do with the b' and \n'. I just don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Why are you redirecting the output of find into a file instead of using check_output with find directly?

Comment: I am completely new to python and coding in general. I will read up on check_output and try implement into my code. Thanks for making me aware of it. If you could give me an example of what it might look like I would really appreciate that.

Comment: You are already using check_output with cat, so I am confused as to why you’re not using it with find.

Comment: wow. I have been looking at this for too long now and couldn't see what was right in front of me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `\n` with [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
output = subprocess.check_output("cat MyDir.txt", shell=True).strip()
os.chdir(output)
```